# Getting error, "Entity doesn't exist in AsyncLocal" when trying to call CreateBatchWrite<T> method of DynamoDBContext object

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, aws-xray

I have created a DynamoDb table in my dev machine and I'm trying to insert couple of rows from my .NET Core application using the `CreateBatchWrite<T>` method of `DynamoDBContext` object. I'm able to query the table from DynamoDB Javascript Shell window from the localhost:8000/shell url and it returns row count as 0. But when trying to call the `CreateBatchWrite<T>` method I get the error, "*Entity doesn't exist in AsyncLocal*".

Answer (score 5):

Add this line before any DynamoDB API methods are executed:

```
AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.ContextMissingStrategy = ContextMissingStrategy.LOG_ERROR;
```

You can find more info in GitHub discussion https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/issues/69#issuecomment-482688754

Also, you will need to import these 2 packages.

```
using Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core;
using Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Strategies;
```

Comment: @HannaHolasava Glad that it helped. Note that this line should be added only during development as per XRay dev guideline: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/xray/latest/devguide/xray-guide.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I missed that too and this line worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

When using X-Ray, this happens when there is an attempt to create a **SubSegment** without a **Parent Segment**. Depending on your setup, when you run a query it might try creating a SubSegment, but it's failing because there is no parent segment.

This is common when running a Lambda function locally, as the **Mock Lambda Test Tool** will not create a **Segment** for you like the actual Lambda environment does on AWS. This can happen in other scenarios too.

More details here: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet/issues/125

### Solution

Easiest way to solve this is disabling X-Ray locally (as you probably don't want to generate traces locally):

In `appsettings.Development.json` add this:

```
"XRay": {
  "DisableXRayTracing": "true",
  "UseRuntimeErrors": "false",
  "CollectSqlQueries": "false"
}
```

The important bit is the `DisableXRayTracing` equals true.

Make sure your `appsettings.Development.json` is set to **Copy Always** in the properties window. You can do this by including this in your `.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="appsettings.Development.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="appsettings.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

> If you really want to trace things locally, then make sure you create
> a parent segment only when running locally (on AWS this would cause
> problems as you would have two parent segments, one created manually
> by you, another one created by AWS).

Comment: This is not working for me in VS 2022 17.4.1 and a net6 minimal api lambda. I ended up addig `#if !DEBUG AWSSDKHandler.RegisterXRayForAllServices(); #endif` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tracing requests made with the AWS SDK, the X-Ray SDK attempts to generate a subsegment automatically to represent those requests, such as `CreateBatchWrite`. However, a subsegment can only be created as the child of an existing Segment, so if you have not created a segment beforehand that `Entity doesn't exist` error will occur.

See these [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet#segment) for how to create custom segments. Alternatively, if you are developing a web app, the X-Ray SDK can automatically create segments for requests made to your service by adding configuration described in these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-dotnet-messagehandler.html#xray-sdk-dotnet-messagehandler-startupcs)